# Categories an JSON API dependent to column value

Tags: php, json, pdo

I'm trying to create JSON API for table of 100 channels and there is a cat column which contain the type or category of each channel.

So I have 4 categories (music, anime, series, movies) each channel has one of these categories in it's cat column.

What I am trying to do is create JSON start with array and inside array there are 4 objects of categories that I mention above and inside each object there is an array for channels belong to that object for example in music object there is an array of channels for all channels have music in it's cat column and so on.

### PHP

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

include_once 'dbconfig.php';

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

$channels = new Channels($db);

$stmt = $channels->read();
$num = $stmt->rowCount();

if($num>0){

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        $cat1=$row['cat'];

        $query2 = "SELECT
                *
            FROM
                channels 
                WHERE cat=$cat1
                ";

        $stmt2 = $db->prepare($query2);

        $stmt2->execute();

        foreach ($stmt2 as $row2) {

        $id=$row2['id'];
        $title=$row2['title'];
        $image=$row2['image'];
        $streamname=$row2['streamname'];
        $enable=$row2['enable'];    
        $cat=$row2['cat'];      
        $app=$row2['app'];

        $channels_item[] = array(
            "id" => $id,
            "title" => $title,
            "image" => html_entity_decode($image),
            "streamname" => $streamname,
            "enable" => $enable,
            "cat" => $cat,
            "app" => $app,
            );
        }

        $channels_item2[] = array(
            "cat" => $cat1,
            "cat_ar" => $cat_ar,
            "channels" => $channels_item,
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($channels_item2);
}

else{
    echo json_encode(
        array("message" => "No products found.")
    );
}

class Channels{

    private $conn;
    private $table_name = "channels";

    public $id;
    public $title;
    public $image;
    public $streamname;
    public $enable;
    public $cat;
    public $app;

    public function __construct($db){
        $this->conn = $db;
    }
function read(){

    $query = "SELECT
                cat
            FROM
                " . $this->table_name . " 
                WHERE app in ('live','live2')
                GROUP BY cat
                ";

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt;
}
}
```

### result that I got:

```
[
{
cat: "music",
channels: null
},
{
cat: "anime",
channels: null
},
{
cat: "series",
channels: null
},
{
cat: "movies",
channels: null
}
]
```

the channels arrays are null as you see
why they are null and can't display the music channels in music cat and display movies channels in movies cat and so on?

Comment: Still a little confused about what you wrote, what result were you expecting, and how exactly does that differ from what you got?

Comment: @JGallardo I just expect from channels array to have objects of rows from table channels depending on the category column, but the channels array is null if u see it in result and this is the problem why it's null and didn't contain channels inside it!